# Display video if image row in database is null in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display video if the image row in database is null and vice versa. For example in my database I have tbl_library which contains columns such as image, video and the primary key is ***library_id***.

I use while loop to view the table information and provide delete and edit button. Delete is working however, I have some issue in edit. If column image is null or empty, I want to display the video using `<video>*video here*</video>` and vice versa if video is empty image will display when I click edit button.

```
<?php  

$define_attachment=mysql_query("SELECT video FROM tbl_library_ads WHERE library_id='$get_id'");

$define_image = mysql_num_rows($define_attachment); 

                                if ($define_image > 0){         
                                echo'
                                <center>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <video width="500" height="350"  style="margin-top:-80px; margin-left:20px;" controls>
                                        <source src="../'.$row['video'].'" type="video/mp4">
                                        </video>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Update Advertisement Video</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="video" value="" accept="video/*">
                                      </div>
                                      </center>';

                             } else {

                                echo'
                                <center>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <img src="../'.$row['image'].'" width="230" height="220"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Update Advertisement Picture</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="image" value="" accept="image/*">
                                      </div>
                                      </center>';

                                 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a column is empty, you can just use `=== NULL` to test whether the column is empty. If `=== NULL` evaluates to true, the column is empty, and you can easily use an `if` statement to show the appropriate HTML markup and edit form.

```
<?php
// Sanitize (you really should be using PDO/prepared stmnts so you don't have to do this)
$get_id = mysql_real_escape_string($get_id);
// Select statement
$define_attachment = mysql_query("SELECT video, image FROM tbl_library_ads WHERE library_id='$get_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($define_attachment)) {
    if ($row['video'] !== NULL) { // If the video column is NOT empty, display the video and the corresponding form
        echo '
        <center>
        <div class="form-group">
        <video width="500" height="350"  style="margin-top:-80px; margin-left:20px;" controls>
        <source src="../'.$row['video'].'" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Update Advertisement Video</label>
        <input type="file" name="video" value="" accept="video/*">
        </div>
        </center>';
    } elseif ($row['image'] !== NULL) { // If the image column is NOT empty, display the image and the corresponding form
        echo '
        <center>
        <div class="form-group">
        <img src="../'.$row['image'].'" width="230" height="220"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Update Advertisement Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" value="" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        </center>';
    }
}
?>
```